# How involved are Edward Baines' parents?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-cell

In The Cell (2000), how involved with the procedure are Edward Baines' parents?

Did they have any say in creating the procedure, help design it in any way, or did they just shell out a ton of money to help fund it?

Later in the film when the FBI gets involved, one of the agents mentions that Edward's parents are both okay with them using the procedure on Carl Stargher. So, obviously, they needed the Baines permission to move forward with their investigation which involved the equipment and the procedure.

Comment: I believe Edward's parents only provided the cash flow to keep the experiment up and running. However, because they probably provided the biggest bit of cash coming in, they were probably given a say in what was done with it. If they weren't happy with any goings on, they'd stop paying. If they stopped paying, the whole procedure, equipment, everything would have come to a halt.